Completing Special hand in canasta
If I am going for a special hand (zip code) and I need 1 card. The tray is empty, and my opponent discards the card I need to complete my special hand. Can I pick that card to complete my special hand?

It depends on the rules your group is following; most commonly no.
Most rule sources for Modern Canasta say that a special hand can only be made after drawing from the deck:
https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#american-special

A special hand is a combination of 14 cards which entitles you to go out by exposing your entire hand after drawing from the deck, without discarding. You are only allowed to put down a special hand if your team has not yet melded any cards. Note that a special hand may include cards matching a closed (complete) canasta melded by the opposing team - i.e. cards that would otherwise be considered 'dead'. Since a special hand cannot use cards taken from the discard pile this does not prevent dead cards from being safe to discard.

https://canasta.com/rules/

If after drawing from the deck you have the cards required for any of the special hands and your team has not yet put down its initial meld you may make the first and only meld for your team by laying down your entire hand without a discard then end the round. All special hands, without exception, contain 14 cards.

However, this site’s rules do allow for this:
https://realcanasta.com/rules

If there is only one discard in the discard pile, you may take that card in order to complete a special hand.

As with many classic card games, there isn’t one official rulebook that can be consulted; so each group will need to agree on which rules they are using.
